# set span position to center

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have multiple `div` with a `image` and a `spam`  and html is :

```
<div style="background:red">
    <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/qku195lvr/graphics_dept.jpg" width="400px" />
   <span class="text">Center Text</span>      
</div>

<div style="background:red">
    <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/qku195lvr/graphics_dept.jpg" width="300px" />
   <span class="text">Center Text</span>      
</div>

<div style="background:red">
    <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/qku195lvr/graphics_dept.jpg" width="500px" />
   <span class="text">Center Text</span>      
</div>
```

and jsfiddel is http://jsfiddle.net/Azb99/3/

i try to set `<span class="text">Center Text</span>` text to center of image and image is dynamic sized.

i try this css :

```
.text {
position:relative;
top:-50%;
left:50%;
text-align:center;
background:#fff;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

how can is set `Center Text` text to center and middle of image ?

see http://jsfiddle.net/Azb99/8/ to help more..

Comment: do you want to put text over the image ?

Comment: yes i want to put text over to image bur image size is not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `absolute` position instead of `relative` for `span` because `relative` is by default position.
Then just play with the `position`ing :)

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Azb99/6/)

```
.text {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    left :25%;
    top:50%;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    color:black;
}
```

**EDIT**

To show on every image, this should be your markup :

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Azb99/7/)

```
div{
    position:relative; /* this is important as its the parent and needs to have a position*/
}
img{
    width:100%; /* make image take full width*/
    height:100%; /* or auto, if you want to maintain aspect ratio */
    position:relative;
    z-index:9; /* to show one over other, lesser z-index will be below */
}
.text {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    left :50%;
    top:50%;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    color:black;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

this is your final result and should get you going!! :)

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Azb99/14/)

```
div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9;
}
.text {
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:99;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    min-height:20px; /* added this */
    top: calc(50% - 20px); /* added this */
    width:100px; /* added this */
    word-break:break-all; /* added this */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin : 0 auto;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    color:black;

}
```

Comment: your demo is mot working text is not showing on every image :(

Comment: your second demo is good to me but, i mention that image size is not fixed... in your second demo there is fixed image size

Comment: @MarkRichards : no its not....i have stretched the image to take full height/width of div....please check the comments added in the **edit** part css...if u still have a doubt..m here :)

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/Azb99/8/ i just try to do `<span class="text">Center Text</span>` to center of every dynamic image (image's size is not fixed), but it's not working.

Comment: @MarkRichards : is changing the markup an option???can we add one more `div` -- *parent div* ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45621/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-mark-richards)

Comment: `left: 50%` results in an overlay starting at 50% left position, but not being really centered…

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you could set a fixed width on the text container, thus you can move it back to the left for the half of its width:

```
figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
figure img {
    display: block;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```